# How to assign multiple possible search value to a <td> when searching/filtering thru it?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to assign multiple hidden values to a `<td>` of a table so that when I search through it, it will still show that value. Kind of like an alt text for tables.

As an example, if I'm building a table of medicines, I want to be able to search for every possible brand names of that medicine.

Here's what I've got so far:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i,alltables;
    alltables = document.querySelectorAll("table[data-name=mytable]");
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  alltables.forEach(function(table){
      tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
          if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
        }       
      }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Meds</h2>

<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable" class="mytable" data-name="mytable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Drug name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Dosage</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Asprin</td>
    <td>1mg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fentanyl</td>
    <td>12mg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ibuprofen</td>
    <td>1mg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Paracetamol</td>
    <td>2mg</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to be able to search for **Tylenol, Mapap or Panadol**(a brand name of paracetamol) and still show paracetamol in the result. If I'm using an alt text(as an example because I don't know what to do) it would look like this:

```
<table id="myTable" class="mytable" data-name="mytable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Drug name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Dosage</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Asprin</td>
    <td>1mg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fentanyl</td>
    <td>12mg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td alt="Advil, Motrin, IBU">Ibuprofen</td>
    <td>1mg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td alt="Tylenol, Mapap or Panadol">Paracetamol</td>
    <td>2mg</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: And what's the actual question/problem? And what have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Comment: I tried solving the problem by adding a hidden <td> but its not working. My question is what's the best way to approach this problem. I can't think of any term that's relevant to this so I'm having a hard time searching for answers in google.

Comment: What exactly is not working with your hidden `<td>`?

Comment: I'm confused why you've included jQuery and then not used it. I would recommend that you the [`data-*` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) and list the alternatives in there, maybe as a CSV. `alt` is an attribute that is used on `<img>` tags and is not appropriate for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you tweak your HTML, like so:

```
<table id="myTable" class="mytable" data-name="mytable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%;">Drug name</th>
    <th style="width:40%;">Dosage</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="datarow">
    <td>Asprin</td>
    <td>1mg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="datarow">
    <td>Fentanyl</td>
    <td>12mg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="datarow">
    <td data-alt="Advil, Motrin, IBU">Ibuprofen</td>
    <td>1mg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="datarow">
    <td data-alt="Tylenol, Mapap or Panadol">Paracetamol</td>
    <td>2mg</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then you could just apply the filter on the row, rather than the cell. Something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i,alltables;
    alltables = document.querySelectorAll("table[data-name=mytable]");
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  alltables.forEach(function(table){
      tr = table.querySelectorAll("tr.datarow");
      for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
          if (tr[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            tr[i].style.display = "";
          } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none";
          }
               
      }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that there will be many data's, So going through each element constantly will be a performance issue. My suggestion would be to specify a size of input after which the search will begin.

Here's my solution

```js
let searchBox = document.querySelector("input"),
  table = document.querySelector("table");

searchBox.addEventListener(
  "input",
  debounce(function () {
    const val = searchBox.value.toLowerCase(),
      tableRows = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");

    if (val.length >= 3) {
      tableRows.forEach((row) => {
        let brands = row.dataset.brands;
        if (brands.includes(val)) {
          row.style.display = "table-row";
        } else {
          row.style.display = "none";
        }
      });
    } else {
      tableRows.forEach((row) => {
        row.style.display = "table-row";
      });
    }
  }, 600)
);
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function () {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    var later = function () {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) {
        func.apply(context, args);
      }
    };
    var callout = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callout) {
      func.apply(context, args);
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<input type="search" placeholder="Type in a medicine name">
<table id="medTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Drug Name</th>
      <th>Dosage</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-brands = "a,b,c">
      <td>Aspirin</td>
      <td>1mg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-brands = "d,e,f">
      <td>Fentanyl</td>
      <td>12mg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-brands = "g,h,i">
      <td>Ibuprofen</td>
      <td>1mg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-brands = "j,k,l">
      <td>Paracetamol</td>
      <td>2mg</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```